# Unification of two accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have two accounts "loup blanc" on Math Overflow. One is unregistered, dated Aug 3, 2012 (reputation 26), and the other is registered. Is it possible to unify the two accounts into the second one?

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Contact Us](https://mathoverflow.net/contact) link at the bottom of the page; there's a specific option for account mergers.

Comment: There is also a [help page](http://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts) about this very issue.